# Angular 11 Reactive form validation: Start date is less than End date

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular11, angular-validation

I am using reactive form and trying to use cross field validation for start and End dates.
Start date should be less that end date. Also user should not be able to select date greater than today date.
Note: I am not using matdatepicker.
Following is my implementation:

```
export const dateValidator: ValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
const start = control.get('dateStart');
const end = control.get('dateEnd');
console.log("validators called");  
return start !== null && end !== null && start < end 
? null :{ dateValid:true };
```

};

HTML

```
<p *ngIf="myForm.errors?.dateValid && (myForm.touched ||myForm.dirty)">Please add a valid from and to date</p>
```

myform.ts

```
 constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {
   this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      dateStart: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      dateEnd: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    },{validators:dateValidator});
}
```

Can anyone help me figure what is  wrong with the code?

Comment: try to use condition : (new Date(start) < new Date(end))

Comment: can you please share the part of the ts code that places `dateValidator` on the form?

Comment: is `start.value<end.value` (start and end are the "formControl"s)

Comment: @TheFabio I have shared the part of ts code

Comment: @Eliseo dateStart and dateEnd are formControls

Comment: your "variables" start and date are formControls (when you make `const start=control.get('dateStart')` your variable is the formControl itself)so you need compare the value of this formControls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check control.value, not the control itself.

```js
export const dateValidator: ValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
const start = control.get('dateStart');
const end = control.get('dateEnd');
console.log("validators called");  
return start.value !== null && end.value !== null && start.value < end.value 
? null :{ dateValid:true };
  }
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your response. This solved my issue. Thank you !